# Why are we allowed to modify the form title from a thread pool thread?

Tags: c#, winforms

The awaitable below does not complete at the `await` point and it does not capture the UI context. It means the UI modifying code that follows will be invoked in another thread (thread pool thread in this case).

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, ");

    Task t = Task.Delay(1000);
    await t.ConfigureAwait(false);

    sb.Append($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

    Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

The code above runs without any problem. No error at runtime.

## Question

Why is it allowed to modify UI components in non-UI thread?
Is there something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: We aren't. That `Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();` seems to be setting a field or property, not affecting any UI element

Comment: What is `Text`? How is it tied to the UI? Databinding?

Comment: What is that `Text`? What UI are we talking about? WinForms? WPF? Is `Text` a property to which a WPF element binds? In that case modifying `Text` won't modify the UI, it will notify it to go and read the new values. It's the UI thread that goes and reads `Text` and then updates the bound elements

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: WinForms.

Comment: What is Text then?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Text` is a property of Form. I don't understand your question.

Comment: The question is "what is this code?" Until now you haven't explained what this code was or where it run, ie at the top level of a form. You were forcing people to guess about the stack and the code

Comment: This is an interesting question. I would prefer if trying to update a UI control from a non-UI thread failed fast and consistently. But instead it seems that sometimes fails and sometimes not.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it would be interesting if it was reproducible. No repro

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Not only title but also textbox, label.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit no repro. In a new Winforms project, using this exact code, I get an InvalidOperationException as expected. I though perhaps there was a difference about the title, but there isn't. Did you modify the app.config settings perhaps, to disable this exception?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I can reproduce it: [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/ne3b7t). Windows 10, .NET Framework 4.7.2, C# 7.3, Visual Studio 2017 15.9.11. Plain vanilla new Windows Forms App.

Comment: Consistently crashes for me. .net 4.7.2, Windows 10, VS2019. New windows forms app

Comment: Ok, got it. It crashes with the debugger attached, works without it. Looks like the cross-thread check is activated by default on winform only if the debugger is attached: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,309

Comment: Adding `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;` makes it crash even without the debugger, as expected

Comment: In .net 1.1 there was no cross-thread checks, this was added in .net 2.0. I suppose they made it opt-in to preserve retro-compatibility. WPF does not have this issue since they introduced cross-thread checks right away. Learned something today.

Comment: @Kevin Gosse Yeap, starting with debugging [crashes for me too](https://prnt.sc/ne3h1w). Problem is, I prefer starting without debugging most of the time.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well, you can (and probably should) add `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;` to your projects. I understand why it's not enabled by default, but I wonder why they didn't add it to the new-project template.

Comment: @KevinGosse: You should make it as your answer. I will accept it. Thank  you!

Comment: @Kevin Gosse very helpful, thanks! From now on `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;` will become a must-have line of code in my projects! Btw the `InvalidOperationException` can be catched and handled in the `Application.ThreadException` event.

Comment: While we're there, I opened an issue to see if this could be fixed in .net core: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-thread checks are disabled by default in winforms unless the debugger is attached. This can be seen [in the initialization of the `checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` field](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,309):

```
private static bool checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = Debugger.IsAttached;
```

If I had to guess, I'd say this is an attempt to preserve retro-compatibility. .NET 1.1 did not have cross-thread checks (and back in the days I was left wondering why my apps would mysteriously crash after a few hours), they were added with .NET 2.0. But this is a huge breaking change, and I suppose that's why they made it opt-in. With WPF, cross-thread checks were introduced right-away, so they could activate them for everybody.

In light of this, I strongly recommend to enable cross-thread checks manually in any winform project by adding this line to the entry-point:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: It has a (minuscule) performance cost though. Updating the `Text` property of a `Form` becomes 4% slower with `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` enabled. :-)

Comment: I think a good compromise would be to use a preprocessor directive: #if DEBUG Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true; #endif. I should be able to discover and fix these kind of bugs during development, before releasing the application.