# C# windows forms - question about cross thread events

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, events

Let's say i have created a class name myClass and this class has a property named myValue with any type, doesn't matter, like:

```
class myClass
{
   public delegate void OverTheLimitDlg(int arg);
   public event OverTheLimitDlg OverTheLimit;
   public myClass()
   {
       myValue = 0;
   }
   private int myvalue = 0;
   public int myValue 
   {
      get { return myvalue;}
      set 
      {
         myValue = value;
         if(value > 5)
            OvertheLimit(value);
      }
    }
}
```

I have a winforms label named myLabel on form and i create an object typed myClass at Form Load event, subscribe its OverTheLimit event and start backgroundworker:

```
myClass myObj; 

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myObj = new myClass();
   myObj.OverTheLimit += SubsMethod;
   backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundworker_DoWork(...)
{
   myObj.myValue = 10;
   //Some expressions.
}

private void SubsMethod(int someInt)
{
   myLabel.Text = "Oh it's over the limit!";
}
```

Summary: i create a class that an object instantiated from it can fire an event. I make the object fire the event in a thread and it runs a method that affects a GUI object, an object created and runs at another thread. I didn't try it ever. What is going to happen in a situation like this? Does it cause error? Thanks.

Comment: You could use the BackgroundWorker's [ReportProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress) method when you need to update a value. So, if a value goes beyond the limit your class has defined, you can raise your event from the [ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged) handler. This event is raised in the caller's thread. The UI Thread, here.

Comment: Don't allow bad things to happen and remain unnoticed. `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true` [is your friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55759792/why-are-we-allowed-to-modify-the-form-title-from-a-thread-pool-thread)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is going to happen in a situation like this?

```csharp
myLabel.Text = "Oh it's over the limit!";
```

This line will throw an `InvalidOperationException` when it tries to edit the `myLabel` from the BackgroundWorker thread. WinForms controls must be changed from the thread that they are created on, this is why [`Control.InvokeRequired`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired?view=netframework-4.8) exists.

You can use the following modified version of `SubsMethod()` which will check if the event handler is running on another thread and then invoke the label change on the GUI thread if necessary.

```csharp
private void SubsMethod(int someInt)
{
    if (myLabel.InvokeRequired) {
        myLabel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>SubsMethod(someInt)));
        return;
    }
    myLabel.Text = "Oh it's over the limit!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try your solution. What i wonder is if there is a way to invoke the event where it fires, in setter of myValue property. I mean my object doens't know what is gonna subscribe its event. It may be a winforms control or some other classes static method that doesn't affects any winforms control. If there is a way to invoke it at the start, my object is sure that there will be no problem.

Comment: @Bee- - There is, but you'd need to push some of your UI related code into the `myClass` object - which would be terrible.